# how to control bandwith of ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rss

I'm using Ajax to obtain some rss from other sites. Ajax has to take rss from 5 sites, parse it, and show only most recent news. The problem is that while working (downloading and parsing) my homepage is not responding to user actions (clicking to some link or so). Javascript IS async, ajax call is async but anyway, problem is there.

I need some ideas - what would be the best and shortest way to take rss from several other sites, parse it and show only most recent one WITHOUT blocking my homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't stop an AJAX request from responding with all the data, nor can you (as far as I know) treat it as a stream.

There are two better ways to acheive what you want:

- Server cache, have the server request/parse the data, save it, and feed it to the site.  It can update it's saved response every *n* minutes
- Ask the data providers to change their format/provide you with a format you require.

Option 1 is probably easiest to implement and fastest for your visitors.  5 ajax requests will always be quite slow.

Comment: Option 1 seems very interesting. Can you give me some url which explains how to do it?

Comment: Instead of Ajaxing the live data, have your server do this every 5 minutes and save it's result to a database.  Have a page, like feed.aspx, which when requested takes the result from the database and just prints it out.  Then your client pages can Ajax feed.aspx, and not 5 independant data sources.  You don't even need Ajax, you can just make the page directly read from the database.  This of course, is assuming you have access to server side scripts of some description.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, thanks to it i have learned new approach ;)